# Identify server CPU process

Tags: joomla, cpu, cpu-usage, lamp, cpu-load

Is there a Server-Side language or something under a LAMP server that may help to
identify why is a certain -repetitive and huge CPU load- process running in my cPanel managed host that is not caused by visits nor cron jobs???

(The process being run is joomla's 3.6.4 index.php, the load is immense, the process appears and disappears randomly without visits being detected by Google Analytics, and there are only some plugins that have always been there and have just been updated as well as joomla core itself)

Answer (score 1):

At the root level, the load is really caused by the MySQL server. You see, Joomla issues (through the main `index.php` file) queries to the database server (which is typically MySQL in your case), and some of these queries are very heavy, and are causing the load.

Some servers, depending on the configuration, show that the load is caused by the `index.php` file and not by MySQL. The best thing that you can do is to examine the server's slow query log (which may be a bit of a problem for you since you seem to be on a shared host) and optimize the slow queries.

If you have no access to the slow query log, then you can disable plugins/modules on your website one by one until the problem is no more (you can also try to switch to a basic Joomla template). If the problem persists then the problem might be caused by the Joomla core (this is especially the case if you have a huge number of articles and/or high traffic).

Comment: Thank,s helps a lot... But to mark this as an accepted answer I would ask just for some possible explanation on what could be triggering this processes when there are no visits nor cron jobs to it (sometimes up to two at the same time from the SAME index.php script)... In essence... Is it possible for Joomla or Wordpress to run scripts without cron or visit triggers?

Comment: I would check to see if you have been hacked.  Are you up to date on Joomla version?   The complication always is that everything Joomla does is bootstrapped through the index.php.  If this problem has started recently you should look for recently modified files.